# @RolesAllowed doesn't work properly

Tags: java, jboss7.x, cdi, deltaspike, picketlink

I have to restrict the access of a method only to the users who have a certain role.
The IdentityManager is built correctly.

I have this controller class.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
@LoggedIn
public class UserController{

    @RolesAllowed({"tt"})
    public String saveUserChanges() {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

And this class handles the `AccessDeniedException` thrown by the method above `saveUserChanges`.

```
@ExceptionHandler
public class SecurityExceptionHandler {

    public void onAccessDeniedException(@BeforeHandles ExceptionEvent<AccessDeniedException> event) {

        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `AccessDeniedException` is correctly thrown and catched by the `SecurityExceptionHandler` class, but the method `saveUserChanges()` is executed anyway.

Is it right? I want the method `saveUserChanges()` is no longer executed if the user doesn't have the "tt" role.

Answer (score 0):

Have you annotated other functions that fail after `saveUserChanges()` completes?  You annotated your `UserController` with `@Logged` in so whoever is at least logged in can execute all your function and maybe your `@RolesAllowed` annotation isn't working at all.